# How to not show period in Angular DatePipe month abbreviation

Tags: angular

I am using a date pipe on a date field in my application.
For an example, if the date is 2 January 2019, I want it to show "Jan 2019". At the moment, it shows "Jan. 2019"
It adds a period after the three letter abbreviation.

My current expression inside angular curly braces is:

```
{{ currentReportDate | date: 'MMM yyyy' }}
```

According to [DatePipe documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) it should already be displayed without the abbreviation period.

My providers in the app.module file looks like this:

```
 providers: [
    ConfigService,
    AuthGuard,
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: "" },
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "en-AU" },
    { provide: "BASE_URL", useFactory: getBaseUrl },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: "en-AU" },
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS },
    { provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: GestureConfig },
    UserService
  ],
```

Any idea how I can get it to get rid of the period?

Comment: What is the original output of `currentReportDate`?

Comment: currentReportDate as displayed via console.log: Mon Apr 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be displaying the short month according to the Angular locale definition for `en-AU` [Source Code LINK](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/locales/en-AU.ts#L31)

```
export default [

    'en-AU', 
        ...

        ['Jan.', 'Feb.', 'Mar.', 'Apr.', 'May', 'Jun.', 'Jul.', 'Aug.', 'Sep.', 'Oct.', 'Nov.', 'Dec.']***,

        ...
]
```

It appears the moment locale short month format for `en-AU` is a bit different (without the periods):

```
export default moment.defineLocale('en-au', {
    ...
    monthsShort : 'Jan_Feb_Mar_Apr_May_Jun_Jul_Aug_Sep_Oct_Nov_Dec'.split('_'),
    ...
});
```

So maybe you could utilize moment to format your date for you; possibly utililzing this [moment.js pipes for Angular](https://github.com/urish/ngx-moment) package.

Comment: Nice! So now we know the cause.

Comment: 2020 update: these definitions changed in this commit: https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/c77faf566e01e76c7f3488265a84d3029d5cf8cc

The short day format is no longer append with periods.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any real issue with your current code sample apart from your date format is wrong, and should be:

```
{{ currentReportDate | date: 'd MMM yyyy' }}
```

output: `2 Jan 2019`

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grgual

After seeing your comment, you could always do: `{{(currentReportDate | date: 'd MMM yyyy').replace(".", "???")}}` but this is definitely a dirty work around.

Comment: I suspect that one of the providers might be interfering with the display of the MMM abbreviation. Alternatively, it could be the culture. I don't need the day, by the way, just three letter month and full year, space separated.

Comment: @tone I think you should change your question because at the moment is states: *"I want it to show "2 Jan 2019""*. I don't think it is the culture because I use `en-AU` as well. Please see my update.

Comment: Fixed the question. I need to add this in a few places. I was considering creating my own custom pipe, but it looks like its easier for me to just expose another public property in typescript that has it pre-formatted how I want it. Second issue with the code above is that the value is initially null, which the pipe can handle, but putting replace on the end raises can't call replace on null error. Easily fixed with ternary though.

Answer (score 1):

```
const date = 2023-09-15T06:38:52

`{{ date | date:'dd MMM yyyy' }}` => // 15 Sep 2023 6:38 AM
`{{ date | date:'dd MMMM yyyy' }}` => // 15 September 2023 6:38 AM
`{{ date | date:'shortTime'}}` => // 6:38 AM
```

for more date formats refer to this document
https://www.telerik.com/blogs/angular-basics-date-pipe-formats-101-examples

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, I would suggest you to use `formatDate` instead of `DatePipe`, to prevent the conflicts between your providers. I presume you wouldn't want to interfere with your providers because they might be needed in other parts of your component.

On your component.ts, you will first need to import `formatDate`.

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
```

Then, you can make use of `formatDate` by doing this:

```
newDate: Date;
dateString: string;

ngOnInit() {
  this.newDate = new Date('Mon Apr 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)');
  // this.dateString = formatDate(this.newDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a', 'en-AU', '+1100');
  this.dateString = formatDate(this.newDate, 'MMM yyyy', 'en-AU', '+1100');
}
```

This should give you the same desired results too.

[formatDate documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate)

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v7se1p?file=src/app/app.component.ts)